# C# split string of first character occurrence

Tags: c#, string

I thought this was simple but this is just kicking my butt.

I have this string `21. A.Person`  I simply want to get `A.Person` out of this.

I try the following but I only get `21`

```
string[] pName = values[i, j].ToString().Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
pName[1] ???
```

`values[i, j].ToString() = 21. A.Person`  and yes I've verified this.

Comment: This seems like an error somewhere that you aren't showing us. If I run this line of code: `"21. A.Person".Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2)[1]` in linqpad the result is "A.Person". So your code seems fine and your problem is probably elsewhere...

Comment: You should have tried by splitting it by space(' ') character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone is giving you alternate solutions when yours *should* work.
The problem is that values[i, j] must *not* equal `21. A.Person`

I plugged it into a simple test..

```
    [Test]
    public void junk()
    {
        string[] pName = "21. A.Person".Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(pName[1]);
    }
```

What does it print?
`A.Person`
(With the space in the front, because you didn't trim the space)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var substr="";
var indedx = yourString.IndexOf('.');
if(index>-1)
   substr = yourString.Substring(index);
substr=substr.Trim();
```

For string "21. A.Person" should return "A.Person"

Comment: need to add check for -1 as index and be good solution, i think

Answer (score 2):

I would use substring() with the position of the first '.' as your start point:

```
var name = sourceString.Substring(sourceString.IndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string pName = values[i, j].ToString().Substring(values[i, j].ToString().IndexOf('.')+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
  var str = "21. A.Person";
  var index = str.IndexOf('.') +1;
  var substr = str.Substring(index, str.Length - index);
```